Excel Add-in API functionality for storage, identity, and notes
I was directed to ask this question in this forum from here.
We are developing an Excel Add-in in Javascript and want to understand the API better.

Our application needs to store data in a way similar to Google Sheets Properties Service. However, I have not been able to find a method that supports this in the API documentation. For instance, Excel.CustomProperty only supports data up to 255 characters. Is there a method for storing larger amounts of arbitrary data?

Our application needs to behave differently based on which user is accessing the Add-in. However, I have not found a method for getting the user's identity, such as email or username. Is there a method for getting the user's identity without requiring that they login (i.e. we do not want to use SSO or Microsoft Graph)?

Finally, we would like to request that support for Notes be added to the API.


Thanks in advance for the help!

See if CustomXMLPart meets your needs for data storage.
There is no way to know the identity of a user that is not logged in. Is that really what you meant?
I've upvoted the Notes idea. Get your friends and relatives to do so too.
